# GPU Compute Render Setting option not available in Blender 3.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I'm on a Macbook Pro M1 series which technically doesn't have a graphics card but does have a GPU intergrated into the M1 chip.

This is a problem when I try to set the render option to GPU mode - there is no graphic card to point point to in blender system settings.

Is there a work around for this?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you need Blender 3.1 or above to use GPU render with a Macbook.

Comment: Thank you! That was it.